# Download a file on FTP to other FTP server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ftp

this is my first question here, please correct me if a few things are not adequate.

My problem is the following: I have a file on an FTP account of my client's provider, normally it would be simple I copy the HTTP URL, but the provider blocks this options. I want to integrate it into the website and since this famous file is updated every day, I need the request to be by URL. I am suggested to make a script which will upload the file to the server to upload it to my server.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to proceed, where to put this script, or what language to use.

For the website I use Wordpress and WP All Import for loop the file !

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This depends on the server you're using, you should look into **cron jobs**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is use `scp`command (if your site is on a linux server) and then implement a cron job to run  `scp` every day.

Here you have an example of `scp`to get the file from your client's server to your host

```
    scp your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/file.extension /some/local/directory/file.extension
```

This is an example of the same command in cron running every day at 2:30 am

```
    30 2 * * * scp your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/file.extension /some/local/directory/file.extension
```

Keep in mind that `scp` command will ask you for a password, so, the prevent this, you will need to use ssh key pairs between both servers.